# why this function blocks all the broswer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

the function shows the type of file from the database a series of information and displays it in tabular form with next to each row 2 buttons that change the value of a field.

instead the function enable should take as input the id of the button, knowing the id of the button I take the value put in the row I pass to the php page that receiving that value does the update. but it is precisely the enable function that does not work as it should block everything.

```
    <SCRIPT>
      var i=0;
        function showTipo(str){
        $("#demo").remove();

            var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x,t,txt = "";
            //var i=0;
            var a= new Array();
           // obj = { "table":sel, "limit":20 };
           // dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                 $("#secondo").before("<center><div id='demo' class='w3-row-padding w3-padding-64 w3-container'> </div></center>");
                   myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                  $("#demo").prepend("<div>  <table border='1' width='75%'> <tr><th width='25%'>Tipologia</th><th width='25%'>Abilitata</th><th width='25%'>Azioni</th></tr></table><table border='1' id='tab' width='75%'></div> ");

               /*    if(myObj[x].tipologia_abilitata== "2"){}
                   else{}

                 */  

                    for (x in myObj) {
                    i=i+1;
                    if(myObj[x].tipologia_abilitata != "2"){

                     // txt +="<tr><td width='25%'>" + myObj[x].tipologia + "</td> <td  width='25%'> <div id='vero' class='w3-container'>"+myObj[x].tipologia_abilitata + "</div></td></tr> "; 
                    //document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML = "<tr><td width='25%'>" + myObj[x].tipologia + "</td> <td  width='35%'> <div id='vero' class='w3-container'>"+myObj[x].tipologia_abilitata + "</div></td></tr> ";
                       if(myObj[x].tipologia_abilitata == "1")
                    {
                      myObj[x].tipologia_abilitata = "ABILITATO";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                      myObj[x].tipologia_abilitata  = "DISABILITATO ";
                    }
                     txt +="<tr><td width='25%' id='cln'"+ i+">" + myObj[x].tipologia + "</td> <td  width='25%'> "+myObj[x].tipologia_abilitata + "</td> <td width='25%'> <button  id='abil'"+i +" class='w3-button' onClick=Abilita(this.id,i)>Abilita</button> <button id='dis'"+i+ " class='w3-button' onclick=Abilita('./Abilta.php','myObj[x]')'>Disabilità</button></td></tr> "; 
                    }}
                    txt += "</table>" 
                    document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML = txt;





                   }
        $("#tab").after= " <br> <br><button   class:'w3-button'> Aggiungi Tipologia </button>    <button>Modifica</button>";
            };
            xmlhttp.open("POST", "VisualizzaCategorie.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("Nome_ente=" + str);
        }


        //cambio da disabilita ad abilita
        /*function Abilita(id,indice){
        var str;
          var xmlhttp;
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var trovato=false;
            var i=0;
            while(i<=indice || trovato ==false){
             if(id == "abil"+i){
              str= document.getElementById("cln"+i).value
             trovato=true
             }
             i=i+1;
            }
            }
          };
              xmlhttp.open("POST", "Abilita.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send("tipo=" + str);  

        }*/

</SCRIPT>
```

I just can not understand why.

can you help me with the help code? or if the function is completely wrong, is it possible to do the thing I have in mind?

Comment: I don't know if you've noticed but the first sentence is in Italian

Comment: the function blocks everything!

Comment: `$("#tab").after= " <br> <br><button   c......` is invalid syntax if you are wanting to use the built in `after()` method of jQuery

Comment: I only sent a part of the web page but jquey is integrated

Comment: Suggest of a compatiot: when you share source code in international forum, please translate italian words in english if you want the people read your code.

Comment: Inside your for loop, you should use `x`, not `myObj[x]`

Comment: You also have a few references to i and x inside your appends that will not work... for example, `Abilita(this.id,i)` and `Abilita('./Abilta.php','myObj[x]')`